# Android URL openStream 'close' not called

Tags: android

I've enabled Strict Mode in my app to go over any unclosed cursors / input streams.

I've hit a snag where it keeps telling me that I have not closed the input stream properly, despite calling the close.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        AddressBookContact _abContact;

        public DownloadImageTask(AddressBookContact abContact) {
            _abContact = abContact;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
//Load photo from URL
                URL url = new java.net.URL(_abContact.getPhoto());
                in = url.openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(in != null) IOUtils.close(in);
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            ....
        }
```

The error keeps happening at this line specifically

```
in = url.openStream();
```

which is before I even get the chance to close it? Not sure what's happening...

Here's the error that it gives me

```
A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
```

Comment: try adding `url.disconnect()` to `finally` block.

Comment: @Ivan hmmm I don't see a disconnect method available on the URL object?

Comment: Hm, yes, sorry I didn't see that URL is from `java.net`. I never actually used `IOUtils`, but as I see for method `close()` they say Closes a URLConnection. But you have a Stream... Don't know, fishing in the dark. But I would try adding `in.close()` at the end in the `finish` block.

Comment: No worries. I did try to use in.close() instead of IOUtils, giving me the same result.

Comment: this exception pops up even the first time you call that AsyncTask? I found somewhere that a person is claiming that an error in the manifest caused this error. Long shot, but until someone comes up with the answer.